# Braintree with node invalidkeysError

Tags: node.js, reactjs, braintree, braintree-sandbox

I am intergrating Braintree (sandbox mode for now) on my node/react project. When sending the payment payload I am getting error saying

> Error [invalidKeysError]: These keys are invalid: paymentMethodNonce[nonce], paymentMethodNonce[details][expirationMonth], paymentMethodNonce[details][expirationYear], paymentMethodNonce[details][bin], paymentMethodNonce[details][cardType], paymentMethodNonce[details]
> [lastFour], paymentMethodNonce[details][lastTwo], paymentMethodNonce[type], paymentMethodNonce[description], paymentMethodNonce[binData][prepaid], paymentMethodNonce[binData][healthcare], paymentMethodNonce[binData][debit], paymentMethodNonce[binData][durbinRegulated]
> , paymentMethodNonce[binData][commercial], paymentMethodNonce[binData][payroll], paymentMethodNonce[binData][issuingBank], paymentMethodNonce[binData][countryOfIssuance], paymentMethodNonce[binData][productId]

My route controller for payment processing:

```
exports.braintreePayment = async (req, res) => {
    let nonceFromClient = req.body.paymentMethodNonce;
    let amountFromClient = req.body.amount;

    console.log(nonceFromClient)
    console.log(typeof amountFromClient)

   let newTransaction = gateway.transaction.sale({
      amount: amountFromClient,
      paymentMethodNonce: nonceFromClient,
      options: {
          submitForSettlement: true
      }
  }, (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
          console.log(err)
          res.status(500).json(err)
      } else {
          res.json(result)
      }
  })
}
```

Nonce coming back from frontend (as an object)

```
{
  nonce: 'tokencc_bd_n6g4d4_38t2p2_8896c8_dj3wqq_6v2',
  details: {
    expirationMonth: '12',
    expirationYear: '2021',
    bin: '411111',
    cardType: 'Visa',
    lastFour: '1111',
    lastTwo: '11'
  },
  type: 'CreditCard',
  description: 'ending in 11',
  binData: {
    prepaid: 'Unknown',
    healthcare: 'Unknown',
    debit: 'Unknown',
    durbinRegulated: 'Unknown',
    commercial: 'Unknown',
    payroll: 'Unknown',
    issuingBank: 'Unknown',
    countryOfIssuance: 'Unknown',
    productId: 'Unknown'
  }
}
```

and the amount from client is showing 204 and is coming in as a number.

I am not seeing any documentation stating that all of the "error" fields must be filled out in order to process payment. Any clues as to what I am overseeing?

just in case frontend fetch call

```
export const processTransaction = async (userId, token, paymentData) => {
    try {
        const braintreeTransaction = await fetch(`http://localhost/api/braintree/payment/${userId}`, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
                "Content-Type": 'application/json',
                Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(paymentData)
        })
        return await braintreeTransaction.json();
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}
```

Front end chekout call

```
const createPurchase = async () => {
        // Send payment information thru nonce to backend
        try {
            let nonce = await data.instance.requestPaymentMethod()
            if (!nonce) return setData({...data, error: nonce.error}) // TODO: set error properly
            const paymentData = {
                paymentMethodNonce: nonce,
                amount: getTotal(products)
            }
            console.log(paymentData)
           let transactionSuccess = await processTransaction(userId, token, paymentData)
            console.log(transactionSuccess)
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to send the nonce key only ( nonce field ) to server, not the entire instance data. Change it to "paymentMethodNonce: nonce.nonce". The code in your case is:

```
const createPurchase = async () => {
    // Send payment information thru nonce to backend
    try {
        let nonce = await data.instance.requestPaymentMethod()
        if (!nonce) return setData({...data, error: nonce.error}) // TODO: set error properly
        const paymentData = {
            paymentMethodNonce: nonce.nonce,
            amount: getTotal(products)
        }
        console.log(paymentData)
       let transactionSuccess = await processTransaction(userId, token, paymentData)
        console.log(transactionSuccess)
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}
```